# Laravel show page according to authentication status

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Is there any way I can do this configuration in routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
if ( Auth::check() === FALSE ) 
 {
   return homeController@guest<--- Specific Controller's method
 } 
 else 
 {
   return homeController@logged <--- Specific Controller's method
 } 
});
```

I don't want to use redirect since I want to keep `mysite.com/` as the main address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can do everything directly in the route like @Ferticidios answer or have only one controller method like @maytham suggests. But you can also do exactly what you asked for:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    if ( Auth::check() === FALSE ) 
    {
        return App::make('homeController')->callAction('guest', array());
    } 
    else 
    {
        return App::make('homeController')->callAction('logged', array());
    } 
});
```

Comment: Great Solution! only it asks for a second parameter as array, passed an empty one and it works! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    if ( Auth::check() === FALSE ) 
    {
       //Do stuff... get data 
       return Response::view('guest')->with($data);
    } 
    else 
    {
       //Do stuff... get data
       return Response::view('logged')->with($data);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what filters were designed to do in Laravel. There is already on for the built in Auth or you can create your own

```
Route::get('user', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
    return App::make('homeController')->callAction('logged');
}));
```

The default filters can be adjusted in **app/filters.php**

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters